# PublishObjects.Add not working on Excel for MAC

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I have a code that works fine under excel for windows but doesn't work under Excel for Mac (2011):

```
rng_str = "$A$1:$C$20" & (scrsheet_row_indx + 8) & """"
rng_str = Left(rng_str, Len(rng_str) - 1)
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Scorecard.htm"
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
    strFile, "scorecards", rng_str, _
    xlHtmlStatic, "PublishToHtml", "")
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

Please let me know if someone can help me with this - if you need to full code please let me know as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When running macros on a Mac OS you need to be careful when referencing file paths as different separators are used for different operating systems.

In your code you have used `\` in your concatenation with `ThisWorkbook.Path` and `"Scorecard.htm"` however only Windows uses `\` as its separator.

The different separators are as follows:

Windows: `C:\myfolder\mydocument.txt`

Unix: `/usr/myuser/mydocument.txt`

Classic Mac OS: `Hard Drive:My Folder:My Document`

The way round this would be to use `Application.PathSeparator` in replacement of `\` in your concatenation:

```
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Scorecard.htm"
```